# Grails test and @Transactional

Tags: testing, grails, transactions

I have Grails test:

```
class GormTests extends GroovyTestCase {
   static transactional = false
   ...
}
```

I'm trying to mark method as transactional by `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation but following exception arises:

```
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class GormTests]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Transactional` is only for Spring beans - test classes aren't beans. Your best bet is to split the test class into two, one with non-transactional tests and one with.

Comment: Would one have to use the `withTransaction` closure, e.g. `SomeDomainClass.withTransaction { // some logic. }` if they wanted to use the `.find()` function, while in an integration test that has  `static transactional = false` defined?